# Actionscript readonly variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

How can I have a variable which is readonly from the outside but changeable from the inside?

Example code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
        [Bindable]
        public var myVar:String;

        public function MyClass()
        {
            myVar = "Some text here";
        }

        public function myfunc():void
        {
            myVar = "Some other text";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make `myVar` to be readonly from the outside?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create a getter function, but not a setter. However, to avoid warnings, you'll also need to make it as dispatching an event, and also dispatch the event when the value changes.

This would look like ...

```
protected var _myVar;

[Bindable("myVarChanged")]
public function get myVar():String {
  return _myVar;
}

protected function setMyVar(value:String):void {
  if(_myVar != value) {
    _myVar = value;
    dispatchEvent("myVarChanged");
  }
}
```

Although it would be nice to have a public getter and a protected/private setter, that causes compilation errors.

Comment: You can also use the standard <code>propertyChange</code> binding notification event - use <code>dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, 'myVar', oldValue, newValue)</code>

Answer (score 2):

Make it private, and create a getter with no setter:

```
private var _myVar:String;

public function get myVar():String {
  return this._myVar;
}
```

I think you can use [Bindable] on the getter which will mean that the property will be a source for data-binding.